# Splitting a list of strings with a delimiter and adding to new lists

Tags: python, string, list, split

This is my list:

```
names = ['blue v orange', 'white v black', 'red v brown']
```

I want to split them by `' v '` and append to a new list like this:

```
['blue', 'white', 'red']  # first
['orange', 'black', 'brown']  # second
```

How can I append them after splitting? The below code does not work:

```
first = []
second = []

for x in names:
    first, second = x.split(' v ')
```

Comment: So your question is: "How do I add an item to a list in Python?"

Comment: Be careful: part of the problem is that you are re-using the variable names `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pythonic solution:

```
names = ['blue v orange', 'white v black', 'red v brown']

x, y = list(zip(*(k.split(' v ') for k in names)))

x  # ('blue', 'white', 'red')
y  # ('orange', 'black', 'brown')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip`:

```
names = ['blue v orange', 'white v black', 'red v brown']  
first, second = map(list, zip(*map(lambda x:x.split(' v '), names)))  
print(first)
print(second)
```

Output:

```
['blue', 'white', 'red'] 
['orange', 'black', 'brown']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append to each list separately, but be careful not to reuse your variable names:

```
names = ['blue v orange', 'white v black', 'red v brown']  
first = []
second = []
for x in names:
    f, s = x.split(' v ')
    first.append(f)
    second.append(s)

print(first, second)
```

Results in:

```
['blue', 'white', 'red'] ['orange', 'black', 'brown']
```